# How to generate auto header file with using makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am working on a project which has a large source code. I want to create a header file which includes specific environment variables using makefile while the project is being compiled because the project has different types. I want to use header file anywhere in the project because I don't want to include some code snippets or vice versa while project is being compiled. How can I do it?

Comment: First, choose a language, C or C++; don't dual tag questions without more reason than is shown in this question.  Next, how do you plan to create the header with environment variables?  Running a shell script if the header doesn't exist?  When does the information change?  Every time you compile?  If so, you're likely to recompile the whole project every time.  Yet if you don't, you'll be vulnerable to changes in the environment not be reflected in the code. You probably create a new header and compare the new file with the old (if it exists) and copy the new over the old if there's a change.

Comment: If it's about setting `#define`'s, passing a macro value through as command line argument to the compiler might be an option, e.g. `-D MYSETTING=ABC', too

Comment: Exactly, I want to do like linux kernel autoconf.h file

Comment: autoconf.h uses some pretty advanced trickery to avoid rebuilding every file each time some small variable has changed.   If you want to do that, you'd have to look into how that works....    Also note: with @StephanLechner's approach, if you changed a variable, it might not cause a dependent source file to rebuild (depending on the makefile layout...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution.  The idea is to generate a temporary .h file, and only update the actual .h if the something has changed.   This prevents you from rebuilding every time.

```
 #dummy target that forces another to be run once per make invokation
 .FORCE:

 #target is run once per make
 file.h.gen: .FORCE
      echo "FOO=$(FOO)" > $@
      echo "BAR=$(BAR)" > $@

 #because file.h.gen is always updated, this is run once per make
 file.h : file.h.gen
      rsync --checksum $< $@
```

Note that if you modify *any* variable in file.h, it will need to rebuild *all* the files that depend on it.   If you want, you can break the .h file into multiple files to give better granularity.  For example, you could create a header file per variable, and each source file would only include the variable headers it's interested in.  This way you only rebuild the files you need.